# Solr indexing added/updated requests as 4 though only total of 2 records available in database for the query

Tags: solr, solrj

Solr indexing added/updated requests as 4 though only total of 2 records available in database for the query.

In database table we have only two records that retrieves by the select query but solr indexing says added/updated requests as 4 , I suspect might be due to versioning, as we use delta import in database sometimes that leads to update the data for that record in the database.

Please suggest how can i instruct solr so that it indexes only available records.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whats the unique key been added to the schema.xml.

It seems that you have not added any unique key because of which it seems that its updating the records and keep on adding the new records.